# passing variable to a stored procedure, c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I have a variable "keypress" that gets set when a phone call is made into our system.  The way it is written to our text file is as follows:

```
w.Write(attrColl["keypress"].Value);
```

What I need to do is pass these keypresses as they come in, to a sproc.

So, my first question is how do I pass it to the sproc, the code I have looks like this:

```
mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Q1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = keypress;
mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Q2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = keypress;
```

for example: if the first keypress is 500#, and the second keypress is 300#.
it should look like @Q1 = 500#, and @Q2 = 300#

Do I need to convert the keypress to a string first?  If so, what is the best way of doing that, as I have about 10 questions that are given so I have 10 unique keypresses that come back.

And second, because there is a # sign at the end of every keypress, will the sproc input be a nvarchar as opposed to a int?  Or what is the best way to handle a #.

Any thoughts, suggestion, or documentation is appreciated.

Comment: What does the table look like?

Comment: the table is looking for Int, it has about 20 columns so the remaining empty places will be null.  If I could strip the # on the aspx side, that would work great.  I'm thinking maybe an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've assumed that your text file looks a little something like this, all on one line.

> 100#400#900#

I also assume that you've read this line back into a variable of somename.

so

```
        var keypressline = "100#400#900#";
        var keyPresses = keypressline.Split('#');
        for (var i = 0; i < keyPresses.Length; i++)
        {               
            mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Q" + i, keyPresses[i]);
        }
```

I've purposely left @Q as a string.  If you cast to an Integer you will lose the fact if 0 is pressed first.

EDIT : Included load file code

```
string fullPathAndFileName = @"C:\blah\blah.txt";
string keypresses;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fullPathAndFileName)) 
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
    {
        keyPresses = sr.ReadLine();
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, and is great, but I still have a few problems with this method.  Not all keypresses end with a #, most do but not all.  And currently the keypress line is sent to and assembled in the text file, not the aspx.

Comment: You'll need to discuss the pattern in which keypresses are added if the hash is guaranteed delimiter. Go back to the original question and add more detail.